# json object UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json, xcode4

Server returns json object shown as below: its around 51 objects

```
[{"location":"Location1","email":"sriharsha@yahoo.com","phone":"123456"},{"location":"Location2","email":"sriharsha.mandya@gmail.com","phone":"123456789"},
.
.
..
..
..51]
```

I want to assign this value first tableview to locations and detailview with email and phone number...

code I used is below:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    [connection release];

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [responseData release];

    NSDictionary *dictionary = [responseString JSONValue];
    NSArray *response = [dictionary objectForKey:@"location"];

    exercises = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:response];
    [table reloadData];
}
```

where am I wrong please suggest...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From first glance the response string looks like an array of dictionaries

to access the the data try something like

```
NSArray* arrayOfDictionaries = [responseString JSONValue];
NSDictionary* firstDictionary = [arrayOfDictionaries objectAtIndex:0];
```